# How to work with mongoengine connect() method in python+mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm learning mongo and cant really figure out how to work w/ the db correctly.

So atm theres an online database i can read from and i am to calculate different stuff like total number of rows in a collection.
i'm working with a pre-written code, so this is why my questions might sound weird.

1. i connect to mongo throguh the *connect(dbname,dburl)* method. so my question is - since this way i dont have a client or db variables, how do i actually interact with the database after i connect? 
   e.g, say i'm working with the collection database in facebook db. i would imaging something like:

   db = MongoClient(dbname, dburl)

   col = db['posts']

and then i can query and work with col, for example (count number of upvotes):

```
query = {'user_action':'upvote'}
print(col.find(query).count())
```

how do i do the same thing when connect() was used? i feel like this is supposed to be a simplification that opens a portal to mongo for easy use but i cant seem to figure out how to use it

thx!

Comment: Check out the [mongoengine tutorial](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#tutorial)